# Leaflet.js Does not put markers correctly

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I try to create a map by leaflet.js but it does not put the markers correctly. Here my html and js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>    
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    
        <script>
            L_NO_TOUCH = false;
            L_DISABLE_3D = false;
        </script>
    
    <style>html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>
    <style>#map {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}</style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/python-visualization/folium/folium/templates/leaflet.awesome.rotate.min.css"/>
    
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <style>
                #map {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 100.0%;
                    height: 100.0%;
                    left: 0.0%;
                    top: 0.0%;
                }
            </style>
        
</head>
<body>    
            <div class="folium-map" id="map" ></div>
        
</body>
<script>    

            function initMap(data){
                data = eval(data);
                
                data.forEach(e=>{
                
                            var marker = L.marker(
                                [parseFloat(e["latitude"]), parseFloat(e["longtitude"])],
                                {}
                            ).addTo(map);         
                });
            }
  
            var map = L.map(
                "map",
                {
                    center: [37.925886135915356, 40.203187856991775],
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    zoom: 1000,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    preferCanvas: false,
                }
            );
            L.control.scale().addTo(map);

            var tile = L.tileLayer(
                "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                {"attribution": "Data by \u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e, under \u003ca href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\"\u003eODbL\u003c/a\u003e.", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 18, "maxZoom": 18, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false}
            ).addTo(map);
        
    
            var marker = L.marker(
                [30.0, 40.0],
                {}
            ).addTo(map);
            
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var test;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    
                    initMap(xhr.response);
                }
                
            }
            xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/test");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            xhr.send();

</script>
```

[image: here the created map]

data is a json array like:

```
[
0: {address: '346 W Magnolia Ave Auburn, AL 36832 US', latitude: 32.606812966051244, location: 'Auburn', longitude: -85.48732833164195, state: 'Alabama'}
1: {address: '300 20th St S Birmingham, AL 35233 US', latitude: 33.509721495414745, location: 'Birmingham', longitude: -86.80275567068401, state: 'Alabama'}
2: {address: '3220 Morrow Rd Birmingham, AL 35235 US', latitude: 33.59558141391436, location: 'Birmingham', longitude: -86.64743684970283, state: 'Alabama'}
3: {address: '4719 Highway 280 Birmingham, AL 35242 US', latitude: 33.42258214624579, location: 'Birmingham', longitude: -86.6982794650297, state: 'Alabama'}
4: {address: '1821 Cherokee Ave SW Cullman, AL 35055 US', latitude: 34.15413376734492, location: 'Cullman', longitude: -86.84122007667406, state: 'Alabama'}
5: {address: '1759 Montgomery Hwy Hoover, AL 35244 US', latitude: 33.378958029568594, location: 'Hoover', longitude: -86.80380210088629, state: 'Alabama'}
6: {address: '5900 University Dr NW Ste D2 Huntsville, AL 35806 US', latitude: 34.742319254429496, location: 'Huntsville', longitude: -86.6657204641674, state: 'Alabama'}
7: {address: '3871 Airport Blvd Mobile, AL 36608 US', latitude: 30.675337809949887, location: 'Mobile', longitude: -88.143753929995, state: 'Alabama'}
]
```

you can also download the data file from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/jeffreybraun/chipotle-locations/download)

as you see they are overlap. It does not matter how much I have data, map always created as the image. Even I have 10 or 1000 datas, map is same.

Comment: You're using fields `X` and `Y` but the data resides in fields `latitude` and `longitude`, and you're using `eval()` instead of parsing the JSON structure.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks for your reply. Yes I use X and Y because sometimes I have different dataset, I fix it when I use. What is matter between JSON structure and eval function, Because both return correct data structure.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

longitude and latitude were not working because I was using different datasets. In the dataset I'm working in, I converted the ["X"] and ["Y"] columns to float type and the javascript was not reading after the comma, for example [40,268472646] read it as javascript [40] and the locations were overlapping
The solution was to convert [","] commas ["."] to dots with replace. Javascript now read [40.268472646] so all locations were visible on the map